# "Keep" function in iMessages iOS 10

Tags: ios, messages

What's this "keep" function appearing next to each message in the new iOS 10 iMessages app? Where does it "save" messages (if it does) and how to get rid of the "saved" ones?

Answer (score 1):

The keep function saves attachments. The attachments are saved in chat information. Tap the i in the top right of your conversation with someone. Then tap attachments and all the kept attachments are there. You can delete them by holding down on them and tapping delete.